# Compiler error using "if" statements in C

Tags: c

I am trying to write a very simple application that allows me to enter a number which will allocate a particular grade.

I've not used the C language very much as i primarily use C# however i still don't seem to be able to get around the errors:

They are all syntax errors, ranging from "if" to "{" although i'm sure everything is as it should be.

One i don't understand is the "void illegal with all types" at the `grade = assess(mark);`
section.

I understand the program may not product the correct output but im simply trying to get it to compile.

Thank you for your help, i imagine I'm doing something REALLY obvious.

Task.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//Protoype
void assess(int* mrk);

// Main method (start point of program)
void main()
{

 int mark;
 char grade;


 printf("enter a word: ");
 scanf("%d", &mark);

 grade = assess(mark);



 printf("That equals ");
 printf("%c", grade);
 printf(" when marked\n");
}


char assess(int* mrk)
{
 char result;

 if(mrk > 0 && <= 100)
 {
  if(mrk < 35)
  {
   result = "f";
  }
  if(mrk >= 35 && <= 39)
  {
   result = "e";
  }
  if(mrk >= 40 && <= 49)
  {
   result = "d";
  }
  if(mrk >= 50 && <= 59)
  {
   result = "c";
  }
  if(mrk >= 60 && <= 69)
  {
   result = "b";
  }
  if(mrk > 70)
  {
   result = "a";
  }
 }
 else
 {
  result = "error";
 }

 return result;
}
```

Comment: sth merely retagged your post; it was tagged as [`c#`] and [`.net`] and [`visual-studo-2008`] but removed those tags and added the tag [`c`]. I further removed the [`visual-studio-2008`] tag.

Comment: You shouldn't `void main` in C.

Comment: @Jason Thankyou, Chrome seems to autocomplete for me.
@Alok Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mrk` is declared as a pointer to an `int` but you are not dereferencing it.

Replace

```
char assess(int* mrk)
```

with

```
char assess(int mrk)
```

in the definition of `assess`

Similarly, you declared (prototyped) `assess` as

```
void assess(int* mrk)
```

Replace with

```
char assess(int mrk)
```

Next,

```
if(mrk >= 35 && <= 39)
```

is not legal syntax. I know it reads like `mrk` is greater than or equal to `35` and less than or equal to `39` but you have to be more explicit for the compiler. So

replace

```
if(mrk >= 35 && <= 39)
```

with

```
if(mrk >= 35 && mrk <= 39)
```

and similarly throughout.

Next, in `assess` you have declared `result` as a `char` but you are assigning `char *`s to result. Replace

```
result = "f";
```

with

```
result = 'f';
```

and similarly for all assignments to `result`. In particular

```
result = "error";
```

should be something like

```
result = 'z'; /* 'z' indicates failure */
```

Comment: Just to elaborate on why `mrk >= 35 && <= 39` doesn't work . . . think about how the statement is evaluated.  What should happen is the left side of the `&&` evaluates to true/false, the right side of the `&&` evaluates to true/false, and then the `&&` combines them.  But as you had it, you have an expression to the right of `&&` that can't be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Your function prototype is void and the implementation is char as a return type. Also you're passing a parameter as a pointer....you should not use a pointer to pass ints unless you want to change the int that was passed in. Passing pointers for ints isn't a speedup since you end up passing a pointer that is the same size as an int anyway.

Comment: I've upvoted the answer, i can't believe i missed this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the fixed version:

- Prototype `assess` was using a pointer to int, but it was not needed as you were calling the function with a parameter as being pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference.
- The function was of the wrong return type, in your prototype you had `void` yet coded the function to return a `char`, that explains the error message your compiler notified about.
- In the function `assess`, incorrect usage of the quotes for the grades, a single quote is a `char`acter, a double quote is a string (type would be `char string[]` or `char *ptrStr`), and the function returned a string type which collided with the `char` return type as per the function signature.
- Lastly but not least, you returned a "error", again a string type, I made that to be 'n' to represent '**n**ot good'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//Protoype
char assess(int mrk);

// Main method (start point of program)
void main()
{

    int mark;
    char grade;


    printf("enter a word: ");
    scanf("%d", &mark);

    grade = assess(mark);



    printf("That equals ");
    printf("%c", grade);
    printf(" when marked\n");
}


char assess(int mrk)
{
    char result;

    if(mrk > 0 && <= 100)
    {
        if(mrk < 35)
        {
            result = 'f';
        }
        if(mrk >= 35 && <= 39)
        {
            result = 'e';
        }
        if(mrk >= 40 && <= 49)
        {
            result = 'd';
        }
        if(mrk >= 50 && <= 59)
        {
            result = 'c';
        }
        if(mrk >= 60 && <= 69)
        {
            result = 'b';
        }
        if(mrk > 70)
        {
            result = 'a';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result = 'n';
    }

    return result;
}
```

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.